# How to merge and overwrite first array with second array?

Tags: php

Following is the two arrays -

```
$a1 = json_decode('[{"id":1,"name":"view_users","checked":false},{"id":2,"name":"add_users","checked":false},{"id":3,"name":"edit_users","checked":false},{"id":4,"name":"delete_users","checked":false},{"id":5,"name":"view_coupons","checked":false},{"id":6,"name":"add_coupons","checked":false},{"id":7,"name":"edit_coupons","checked":false},{"id":8,"name":"delete_coupons","checked":false},{"id":9,"name":"view_roles","checked":false},{"id":10,"name":"add_roles","checked":false},{"id":11,"name":"edit_roles","checked":false},{"id":12,"name":"delete_roles","checked":false},{"id":13,"name":"view_payment_requests","checked":false},{"id":14,"name":"add_payment_requests","checked":false},{"id":15,"name":"edit_payment_requests","checked":false},{"id":16,"name":"delete_payment_requests","checked":false},{"id":17,"name":"view_requests_orders","checked":false},{"id":18,"name":"add_requests_orders","checked":false},{"id":19,"name":"edit_requests_orders","checked":false},{"id":20,"name":"delete_requests_orders","checked":false}]', true);

$a2 = json_decode('[{"id":2,"name":"add_users","checked":true},{"id":4,"name":"delete_users","checked":true},{"id":5,"name":"view_coupons","checked":true},{"id":6,"name":"add_coupons","checked":true},{"id":12,"name":"delete_roles","checked":true}]', true);
```

I want it to be like the following after merge and overwrite -

```
$final_output = json_decode('[{id: 1, name: "view_users", checked: false}, {id: 2, name: "add_users", checked: true}, {id: 3, name: "edit_users", checked: false}, {id: 4, name: "delete_users", checked: true}, {id: 5, name: "view_coupons", checked: true}, {id: 6, name: "add_coupons", checked: true}, {id: 7, name: "edit_coupons", checked: false}, {id: 8, name: "delete_coupons", checked: false}, {id: 9, name: "view_roles", checked: false}, {id: 10, name: "add_roles", checked: false}, {id: 11, name: "edit_roles", checked: false}, {id: 12, name: "delete_roles", checked: true}, {id: 13, name: "view_payment_requests", checked: false}, {id: 14, name: "add_payment_requests", checked: false}, {id: 15, name: "edit_payment_requests", checked: false}, {id: 16, name: "delete_payment_requests", checked: false}, {id: 17, name: "view_requests_orders", checked: false}, {id: 18, name: "add_requests_orders", checked: false}, {id: 19, name: "edit_requests_orders", checked: false}, {id: 20, name: "delete_requests_orders", checked: false}]', true)
```

I've tried to do this using the following php methods but I'm not getting the proper result.

```
$merged1 = array_merge($a1, $a2);
$merged2 = array_merge_recursive($a1, $a2);
$merged3 = array_replace($a1, $a2);
$merged4 = array_replace_recursive($a1, $a2);
```

None of the above methods yield the final output.
I couldn't able to figure out what is wrong here. Please suggests me, how can I get the final output. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I fail to understand how you want to achieve what you suggest... Take the element with ID 1 for example: in the input it has the property "checked" set to FALSE, in your proposed result it should suddenly be TRUE. How that?

Comment: @arkascha I did a mistake at the time of questioning! I've corrected the `$final_output` .Could you please help me with this? How can I achieve the `$final_output`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care to preserve the actual position of the elements...

```
<?php
$aIn = [
  json_decode('[{"id":1,"name":"view_users","checked":false},{"id":2,"name":"add_users","checked":false},{"id":3,"name":"edit_users","checked":false},{"id":4,"name":"delete_users","checked":false},{"id":5,"name":"view_coupons","checked":false},{"id":6,"name":"add_coupon
  json_decode('[{"id":2,"name":"add_users","checked":true},{"id":4,"name":"delete_users","checked":true},{"id":5,"name":"view_coupons","checked":true},{"id":6,"name":"add_coupons","checked":true},{"id":12,"name":"delete_roles","checked":true}]', true)
];

$aOut = [];
foreach($aIn as $aX) {
  array_walk($aX, function($entry) use (&$aOut) {
    $aOut[$entry['id']] = $entry;
  });
}

print_r(json_encode(array_values($aOut)));
```

The output is:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"view_users","checked":false},{"id":2,"name":"add_users","checked":true},{"id":3,"name":"edit_users","checked":false},{"id":4,"name":"delete_users","checked":true},{"id":5,"name":"view_coupons","checked":true},{"id":6,"name":"add_coupons","checked":true},{"id":7,"name":"edit_coupons","checked":false},{"id":8,"name":"delete_coupons","checked":false},{"id":9,"name":"view_roles","checked":false},{"id":10,"name":"add_roles","checked":false},{"id":11,"name":"edit_roles","checked":false},{"id":12,"name":"delete_roles","checked":true},{"id":13,"name":"view_payment_requests","checked":false},{"id":14,"name":"add_payment_requests","checked":false},{"id":15,"name":"edit_payment_requests","checked":false},{"id":16,"name":"delete_payment_requests","checked":false},{"id":17,"name":"view_requests_orders","checked":false},{"id":18,"name":"add_requests_orders","checked":false},{"id":19,"name":"edit_requests_orders","checked":false},{"id":20,"name":"delete_requests_orders","checked":false}]
```